# Using ffmpeg to combine images and audio into a video file - how to add animations/transitions

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to combine mutiple images with an audio file to generate one video. I got this working using following php code:

```
<?php
//Created fucntion to combine images using FFMPEG in php
function mix_video($audio_file, $video_file) {

    //Here I have used ffmpeg command in php

    echo  $ffmpeg = "ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 " . $audio_file . " -vcodec mpeg4 -s 720x576 -b 10k -r 1 -acodec copy -shortest " . $video_file;
    echo shell_exec($ffmpeg);
}

//Run Function
$audio_file = "Ballad_of_the_Sneak.mp3";
$video_file = "newvideo.mp4";

mix_video($audio_file, $video_file);
```

As an output from this code I got a new video file, which is working fine. Now I want to add **animation** to images like fade in, fade out, slide in, slide out, drop from top etc.

How can I achieve this using ffmpeg commands? Or is there another way?